# DataTables 1.10 serverside with table joins returning 'null' value responses

Tags: php, sql, pdo, datatables

I am trying to modify the default serverside scripting for DataTables 1.10 (the latest which is in beta right now) to allow for table joins and custom 'WHERE' conditions.  The 'WHERE' conditions work fine as I did this previously, however, I am having some trouble with table joins.  I made some progress earlier (I am no longer receiving any errors in firebug), but all columns of each row are returning a null value as the response.  In other words, my table shows on the page with all empty columns for each row.

I have tried the datatables forum, but did not get much luck.  For simplicity I have not included everything, but have included the serverside php processing script and the ssp.class.php script as well.

**processing.php :**

```
// DB table to use
$table = "`users`";

// Join condition
$myJoin = "LEFT JOIN `security` ON `users`.`user_id` = `security`.`user_id`";


// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = "`users`.`user_id`";

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`settings_id`', 'dt' => 'settings_id' ),
    array( 'db' => '`users`.`user_id`', 'dt' => 'user_id' ),
    array( 'db' => '`users`.`username`', 'dt' => 'username' ),
    array( 'db' => '`users`.`computer_name`', 'dt' => 'computer_name' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_desktop`', 'dt' => 'disable_desktop' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_start`', 'dt' => 'disable_start' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_shutdown`', 'dt' => 'disable_shutdown' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_run`', 'dt' => 'disable_run' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_mouse`', 'dt' => 'disable_mouse' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_bootkeys`', 'dt' => 'disable_bootkeys' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_cp`', 'dt' => 'disable_cp' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_network`', 'dt' => 'disable_network' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_taskbar`', 'dt' => 'disable_taskbar' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_clock`', 'dt' => 'disable_clock' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_logoff`', 'dt' => 'disable_logoff' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_startchange`', 'dt' => 'disable_startchange' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_taskman`', 'dt' => 'disable_taskman' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_clipboard`', 'dt' => 'disable_clipboard' ),
    array( 'db' => '`security`.`disable_drives`', 'dt' => 'disable_drives' )
);

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $db, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $myJoin, "")
    //SSP::simple( $_GET, $db, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $myJoin, $myWhere)
);
```

**ssp.class.php :**

```
class SSP {
    /**
     * Create the data output array for the DataTables rows
     *
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  array $data    Data from the SQL get
     *  @return array          Formatted data in a row based format
     */
    static function data_output ( $primaryKey, $columns, $data )
    {
        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($data) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $row = array();

            for ( $j=0, $jen=count($columns) ; $j<$jen ; $j++ ) {
                $column = $columns[$j];    
                // Is there a formatter?
                if ( isset( $column['formatter'] ) ) {
                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $column['formatter']( $data[$i][ $column['db'] ], $data[$i] );
                }
                else {
                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];
                }

            }


            $out[] = $row;
        }

        return $out;
    }


    /**
     * Paging
     *
     * Construct the LIMIT clause for server-side processing SQL query
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return string SQL limit clause
     */
    static function limit ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $limit = '';

        if ( isset($request['start']) && $request['length'] != -1 ) {
            $limit = "LIMIT ".intval($request['start']).", ".intval($request['length']);
        }

        return $limit;
    }


    /**
     * Ordering
     *
     * Construct the ORDER BY clause for server-side processing SQL query
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return string SQL order by clause
     */
    static function order ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $order = '';

        if ( isset($request['order']) && count($request['order']) ) {
            $orderBy = array();
            $dtColumns = SSP::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['order']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                // Convert the column index into the column data property
                $columnIdx = intval($request['order'][$i]['column']);
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$columnIdx];

                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['orderable'] == true ) {
                    $dir = $request['order'][$i]['dir'] === 'asc' ?
                        'ASC' :
                        'DESC';

                    $orderBy[] = ''.$column['db'].' '.$dir;
                }
            }

            $order = 'ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $orderBy);
        }

        return $order;
    }


    /**
     * Searching / Filtering
     *
     * Construct the WHERE clause for server-side processing SQL query.
     *
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here performance on large
     * databases would be very poor
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  array $bindings Array of values for PDO bindings, used in the
     *    sql_exec() function
     *  @return string SQL where clause
     EDIT : added $mywhere functionality for passing initial filtering conditions
     */
    static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings, $myWhere )
    {
        $globalSearch = array();
        $columnSearch = array();
        $dtColumns = SSP::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

        if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
            $str = $request['search']['value'];

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                    $binding = SSP::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $globalSearch[] = "".$column['db']." LIKE ".$binding;
                }
            }
        }

        // Individual column filtering
        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
            $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
            $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

            $str = $requestColumn['search']['value'];

            if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' &&
             $str != '' ) {
                $binding = SSP::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $columnSearch[] = "".$column['db']." LIKE ".$binding;
            }
        }

        // Combine the filters into a single string
        $where = '';

        if ( count( $globalSearch ) ) {
            $where = '('.implode(' OR ', $globalSearch).')';
        }

        if ( count( $columnSearch ) ) {
            $where = $where === '' ?
                implode(' AND ', $globalSearch) :
                $where .' AND '. implode(' AND ', $globalSearch);
        }

        if ( $where !== '' ) {
            $where = 'WHERE '.$where;

            // add my clause
            if ($myWhere !== '') {
                $where .= ' AND '.$myWhere;
            }
        }

        if ( $where == '' && $myWhere !== '') {
            // add my clause
            $where = 'WHERE '.$myWhere;
        }       

        return $where;
    }


    /**
     * Perform the SQL queries needed for an server-side processing requested,
     * utilising the helper functions of this class, limit(), order() and
     * filter() among others. The returned array is ready to be encoded as JSON
     * in response to an SSP request, or can be modified if needed before
     * sending back to the client.
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $sql_details SQL connection details - see sql_connect()
     *  @param  string $table SQL table to query
     *  @param  string $primaryKey Primary key of the table
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return array          Server-side processing response array
     */
    static function simple ( $request, $db, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $myJoin, $myWhere )
    {
        $bindings = array();
        //$db = SSP::sql_connect( $sql_details );

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = SSP::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = SSP::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = SSP::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings, $myWhere );    

        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = SSP::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".implode(", ", SSP::pluck($columns, 'db'))."
             FROM $table
             $myJoin
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
        );

        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = SSP::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];  

        //add my initial where clause for correct results
        $dataWhere = ($myWhere !== '' ? 'WHERE '.$myWhere : '');

        // Total data set length        
        $resTotalLength = SSP::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT COUNT({$primaryKey})
             FROM $table
             $myJoin
             $dataWhere"
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];


        /*
         * Output
         */          
        return array(
            "draw"            => intval( $request['draw'] ),
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => SSP::data_output( $primaryKey, $columns, $data )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Execute an SQL query on the database
     *
     * @param  resource $db  Database handler
     * @param  array    $bindings Array of PDO binding values from bind() to be
     *   used for safely escaping strings. Note that this can be given as the
     *   SQL query string if no bindings are required.
     * @param  string   $sql SQL query to execute.
     * @return array         Result from the query (all rows)
     */
    static function sql_exec ( $db, $bindings, $sql=null )
    {
        // Argument shifting
        if ( $sql === null ) {
            $sql = $bindings;
        }

        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
        //echo $sql;

        // Bind parameters
        if ( is_array( $bindings ) ) {
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($bindings) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $binding = $bindings[$i];
                $stmt->bindValue( $binding['key'], $binding['val'], $binding['type'] );
            }
        }

        // Execute
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            SSP::fatal( "An SQL error occurred: ".$e->getMessage() );
        }

        // Return all
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Internal methods
     */

    /**
     * Throw a fatal error.
     *
     * This writes out an error message in a JSON string which DataTables will
     * see and show to the user in the browser.
     *
     * @param  string $msg Message to send to the client
     */
    static function fatal ( $msg )
    {
        echo json_encode( array( 
            "error" => $msg
        ) );

        exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Create a PDO binding key which can be used for escaping variables safely
     * when executing a query with sql_exec()
     *
     * @param  array &$a    Array of bindings
     * @param  *      $val  Value to bind
     * @param  int    $type PDO field type
     * @return string       Bound key to be used in the SQL where this parameter
     *   would be used.
     */
    static function bind ( &$a, $val, $type )
    {
        $key = ':binding_'.count( $a );

        $a[] = array(
            'key' => $key,
            'val' => $val,
            'type' => $type
        );

        return $key;
    }


    /**
     * Pull a particular property from each assoc. array in a numeric array, 
     * returning and array of the property values from each item.
     *
     *  @param  array  $a    Array to get data from
     *  @param  string $prop Property to read
     *  @return array        Array of property values
     */
    static function pluck ( $a, $prop )
    {
        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $len=count($a) ; $i<$len ; $i++ ) {
            $out[] = $a[$i][$prop];
        }

        return $out;
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Here is the result of `SSP::data_output( $primaryKey, $columns, $data )`.  I had to print this to a file because I could not print/show on screen.  Pretty obvious from the results that something is up with the data portion of the code as it returns nothing, however, it is returning the correct number of results (in this case 5). Note that the naming is different as these are the names returned back to DataTables and not the actual db column names, however, that probably has something to do with it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [settings_id] => 
            [user_id] => 
            [username] => 
            [computer_name] => 
            [disable_desktop] => 
            [disable_start] => 
            [disable_shutdown] => 
            [disable_run] => 
            [disable_mouse] => 
            [disable_bootkeys] => 
            [disable_cp] => 
            [disable_network] => 
            [disable_taskbar] => 
            [disable_clock] => 
            [disable_logoff] => 
            [disable_startchange] => 
            [disable_taskman] => 
            [disable_clipboard] => 
            [disable_drives] => 
            [DT_RowId] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [settings_id] => 
            [user_id] => 
            [username] => 
            [computer_name] => 
            [disable_desktop] => 
            [disable_start] => 
            [disable_shutdown] => 
            [disable_run] => 
            [disable_mouse] => 
            [disable_bootkeys] => 
            [disable_cp] => 
            [disable_network] => 
            [disable_taskbar] => 
            [disable_clock] => 
            [disable_logoff] => 
            [disable_startchange] => 
            [disable_taskman] => 
            [disable_clipboard] => 
            [disable_drives] => 
            [DT_RowId] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [settings_id] => 
            [user_id] => 
            [username] => 
            [computer_name] => 
            [disable_desktop] => 
            [disable_start] => 
            [disable_shutdown] => 
            [disable_run] => 
            [disable_mouse] => 
            [disable_bootkeys] => 
            [disable_cp] => 
            [disable_network] => 
            [disable_taskbar] => 
            [disable_clock] => 
            [disable_logoff] => 
            [disable_startchange] => 
            [disable_taskman] => 
            [disable_clipboard] => 
            [disable_drives] => 
            [DT_RowId] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [settings_id] => 
            [user_id] => 
            [username] => 
            [computer_name] => 
            [disable_desktop] => 
            [disable_start] => 
            [disable_shutdown] => 
            [disable_run] => 
            [disable_mouse] => 
            [disable_bootkeys] => 
            [disable_cp] => 
            [disable_network] => 
            [disable_taskbar] => 
            [disable_clock] => 
            [disable_logoff] => 
            [disable_startchange] => 
            [disable_taskman] => 
            [disable_clipboard] => 
            [disable_drives] => 
            [DT_RowId] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [settings_id] => 
            [user_id] => 
            [username] => 
            [computer_name] => 
            [disable_desktop] => 
            [disable_start] => 
            [disable_shutdown] => 
            [disable_run] => 
            [disable_mouse] => 
            [disable_bootkeys] => 
            [disable_cp] => 
            [disable_network] => 
            [disable_taskbar] => 
            [disable_clock] => 
            [disable_logoff] => 
            [disable_startchange] => 
            [disable_taskman] => 
            [disable_clipboard] => 
            [disable_drives] => 
            [DT_RowId] => 
        )

)
```

Further info - viewing of $data at this point of the code shown below returns all the correct values.

```
$data = SSP::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
    "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".implode(", ", SSP::pluck($columns, 'db'))."
     FROM $table
     $myJoin
     $where
     $order
     $limit"
);
```

Here is a portion (one row) of the returned array with correct values from the above :

```
[3] => Array
    (
        [settings_id] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [user_id] => 11
        [1] => 11
        [username] => steve
        [2] => steve
        [computer_name] => TESTING
        [3] => TESTING
        [disable_desktop] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [disable_start] => 0
        [5] => 0
        [disable_shutdown] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [disable_run] => 0
        [7] => 0
        [disable_mouse] => 0
        [8] => 0
        [disable_bootkeys] => 0
        [9] => 0
        [disable_cp] => 0
        [10] => 0
        [disable_network] => 0
        [11] => 0
        [disable_taskbar] => 0
        [12] => 0
        [disable_clock] => 0
        [13] => 0
        [disable_logoff] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [disable_startchange] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [disable_taskman] => 0
        [16] => 0
        [disable_clipboard] => 0
        [17] => 0
        [disable_drives] => 0
        [18] => 0
    )
```

Not entirely sure if this is correct output or not, however, I believe it is as you can refer to the data in datatables by name or index which would explain this output.

**EDIT:**

I have narrowed down the problem a little further.  static function data_output ( $primaryKey, $columns, $data ) is part of the issue as expected.  $primaryKey and $columns have the correct values, however, $data does not.

In the function when you come to the part where it actually sets the values there is no value in the array to be set.

`$row[ $column['dt'] ] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];`

Here `$row[ $column['dt'] ]` is correct, but `$data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];` has no db value. As you can see in the example output of $data above the db values are not present, but instead of the dt values along with the index as the same value.  By changing this to dt my table shows data, however, this breaks a few other things.  I am not sure why $data is not including the db values as it should.

Comment: Try to dump the whole query and try executing them straight to mysql command line, see if there is any error.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly that won't really help.  I could easily query the db with what I want... it is a matter of modifying this script to accept the table joins that I am after.  draw, recordsTotal, and recordsFiltered are being returned properly.  `"data"            => SSP::data_output( $primaryKey, $columns, $data )` seems to be the issue as all columns return null.

Comment: Can you try to dump the $data variable, right after SSP::sql_exec(,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with some changes to the ssp.  Changed include select x AS x to ensure correct table column is fetched as well as minor changes to the data_output function.  $data is now returned correctly.  A bit hacky and could be cleaned up, but it works in all tests I have done so far.

```
class SSP {
    /**
     * Create the data output array for the DataTables rows
     *
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  array $data    Data from the SQL get
     *  @return array          Formatted data in a row based format
     */
    static function data_output ( $columns, $data )
    {
        //show $data values in file since it cannot be echo'ed out
        //file_put_contents('/home/test/public_html/filename.txt', print_r($data, true));

        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($data) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $row = array();

            for ( $j=0, $jen=count($columns) ; $j<$jen ; $j++ ) {
                $column = $columns[$j];

                // Is there a formatter?
                if ( isset( $column['formatter'] ) ) {
                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $column['formatter']( $data[$i][ $column['dt'] ], $data[$i] );
                }
                else {
                    $row[ $column['dt'] ] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['dt'] ];
                }

            }

            $out[] = $row;
        }

        return $out;
    }


    /**
     * Paging
     *
     * Construct the LIMIT clause for server-side processing SQL query
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return string SQL limit clause
     */
    static function limit ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $limit = '';

        if ( isset($request['start']) && $request['length'] != -1 ) {
            $limit = "LIMIT ".intval($request['start']).", ".intval($request['length']);
        }

        return $limit;
    }


    /**
     * Ordering
     *
     * Construct the ORDER BY clause for server-side processing SQL query
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return string SQL order by clause
     */
    static function order ( $request, $columns )
    {
        $order = '';

        if ( isset($request['order']) && count($request['order']) ) {
            $orderBy = array();
            $dtColumns = SSP::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['order']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                // Convert the column index into the column data property
                $columnIdx = intval($request['order'][$i]['column']);
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$columnIdx];

                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['orderable'] == true ) {
                    $dir = $request['order'][$i]['dir'] === 'asc' ?
                        'ASC' :
                        'DESC';

                    $orderBy[] = ''.$column['db'].' '.$dir;
                }
            }

            $order = 'ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $orderBy);
        }

        return $order;
    }


    /**
     * Searching / Filtering
     *
     * Construct the WHERE clause for server-side processing SQL query.
     *
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here performance on large
     * databases would be very poor
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @param  array $bindings Array of values for PDO bindings, used in the
     *    sql_exec() function
     *  @return string SQL where clause
     EDIT : added $mywhere functionality for passing initial filtering conditions
     */
    static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings, $myWhere )
    {
        $globalSearch = array();
        $columnSearch = array();
        $dtColumns = SSP::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

        if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
            $str = $request['search']['value'];

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                    $binding = SSP::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $globalSearch[] = "".$column['db']." LIKE ".$binding;
                }
            }
        }

        // Individual column filtering
        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
            $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
            $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

            $str = $requestColumn['search']['value'];

            if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' &&
             $str != '' ) {
                $binding = SSP::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $columnSearch[] = "".$column['db']." LIKE ".$binding;
            }
        }

        // Combine the filters into a single string
        $where = '';

        if ( count( $globalSearch ) ) {
            $where = '('.implode(' OR ', $globalSearch).')';
        }

        if ( count( $columnSearch ) ) {
            $where = $where === '' ?
                implode(' AND ', $globalSearch) :
                $where .' AND '. implode(' AND ', $globalSearch);
        }

        if ( $where !== '' ) {
            $where = 'WHERE '.$where;

            // add my clause
            if ($myWhere !== '') {
                $where .= ' AND '.$myWhere;
            }
        }

        if ( $where == '' && $myWhere !== '') {
            // add my clause
            $where = 'WHERE '.$myWhere;
        }       

        return $where;
    }


    /**
     * Perform the SQL queries needed for an server-side processing requested,
     * utilising the helper functions of this class, limit(), order() and
     * filter() among others. The returned array is ready to be encoded as JSON
     * in response to an SSP request, or can be modified if needed before
     * sending back to the client.
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array $sql_details SQL connection details - see sql_connect()
     *  @param  string $table SQL table to query
     *  @param  string $primaryKey Primary key of the table
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return array          Server-side processing response array
     */
    static function simple ( $request, $db, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $myJoin, $myWhere )
    {
        $bindings = array();
        //$db = SSP::sql_connect( $sql_details );

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = SSP::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = SSP::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = SSP::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings, $myWhere );    

        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = SSP::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            //"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".implode(", ", SSP::pluck($columns, 'db'))."
            "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".implode(", ", SSP::pluckAs($columns))."
             FROM $table
             $myJoin
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
        );

        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = SSP::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];  

        //add my initial where clause for correct results
        $dataWhere = ($myWhere !== '' ? 'WHERE '.$myWhere : '');

        // Total data set length        
        $resTotalLength = SSP::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT COUNT({$primaryKey})
             FROM $table
             $myJoin
             $dataWhere"
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];      

        /*
         * Output
         */          
        return array(
            "draw"            => intval( $request['draw'] ),
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => SSP::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );

    }

    /**
     * Execute an SQL query on the database
     *
     * @param  resource $db  Database handler
     * @param  array    $bindings Array of PDO binding values from bind() to be
     *   used for safely escaping strings. Note that this can be given as the
     *   SQL query string if no bindings are required.
     * @param  string   $sql SQL query to execute.
     * @return array         Result from the query (all rows)
     */
    static function sql_exec ( $db, $bindings, $sql=null )
    {
        // Argument shifting
        if ( $sql === null ) {
            $sql = $bindings;
        }

        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
        //echo $sql;

        // Bind parameters
        if ( is_array( $bindings ) ) {
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($bindings) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $binding = $bindings[$i];
                $stmt->bindValue( $binding['key'], $binding['val'], $binding['type'] );
            }
        }

        // Execute
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            SSP::fatal( "An SQL error occurred: ".$e->getMessage() );
        }

        // Return all
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Internal methods
     */

    /**
     * Throw a fatal error.
     *
     * This writes out an error message in a JSON string which DataTables will
     * see and show to the user in the browser.
     *
     * @param  string $msg Message to send to the client
     */
    static function fatal ( $msg )
    {
        echo json_encode( array( 
            "error" => $msg
        ) );

        exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Create a PDO binding key which can be used for escaping variables safely
     * when executing a query with sql_exec()
     *
     * @param  array &$a    Array of bindings
     * @param  *      $val  Value to bind
     * @param  int    $type PDO field type
     * @return string       Bound key to be used in the SQL where this parameter
     *   would be used.
     */
    static function bind ( &$a, $val, $type )
    {
        $key = ':binding_'.count( $a );

        $a[] = array(
            'key' => $key,
            'val' => $val,
            'type' => $type
        );

        return $key;
    }


    /**
     * Pull a particular property from each assoc. array in a numeric array, 
     * returning and array of the property values from each item.
     *
     *  @param  array  $a    Array to get data from
     *  @param  string $prop Property to read
     *  @return array        Array of property values
     */
    static function pluck ( $a, $prop )
    {
        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $len=count($a) ; $i<$len ; $i++ ) {
            $out[] = $a[$i][$prop];
        }

        return $out;
    }

    /**
     * Create and return select array in the format `db` AS `dt` 
     * returning and array of the property values from each item.
     *
     *  @param  array  $a    Array to get data from
     *  @return array        Array of property values
     */
    static function pluckAs ( $a )
    {
        $out = array();

        for ( $i=0, $len=count($a) ; $i<$len ; $i++ ) {
            $out[] = $a[$i]['db']." AS `".$a[$i]['dt']."`";
        }

        return $out;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: emranulhadi offers a customized SSP class implementing JOINs and extra conditions (WHEREs):

https://emranulhadi.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/join-and-extra-condition-support-at-datatables-library-ssp-class/

Available on Github: https://github.com/emran/ssp

Answer (score 0):

For the record in the script there is a bug, the next line:

```
    if ( count( $columnSearch ) ) {
        $where = $where === '' ?
            implode(' AND ', $globalSearch) :
            $where .' AND '. implode(' AND ', $globalSearch);
    }
```

MUST BE

```
    if ( count( $columnSearch ) ) {
        $where = $where === '' ?
            implode(' AND ', $columnSearch ) :
            $where .' AND '. implode(' AND ', $columnSearch );
    }
```

I have been searching for days, but this was the error in the php scriptfile.